# php is not recognized as an internal or external command using xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp, so my php folder is in `C:\xampp\php\` and I add in my `PATH` environment variables the `C:\xampp\php\` but when I am running on cmd the `php` command I am getting the following message:

`php is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: is php.exe in c:\xammp\php? Whatever folder php.exe is in what you need to add to your $PATH

Comment: Is you php.exe file in the php folder or in subfolder like php\php5.3.8

Comment: `php.exe` is located on `C:\xampp\php` . I am using Windows8.

Comment: Have you logged in and out again? It might sound stupid, but I remember that for some Windows versions I had to do that in order for PATH to be refreshed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding an entry to **environment variables** make sure you leave no spaces between the semicolon and the new path.

I spent a couple of hours going over my steps until I realized that the only difference between other path entries and mine was a single empty space. So i changed it and tried again at the command window (**no need to log off and back on**) and it worked!

I realize this was asked a while ago but since I found myself looking for a solution i figured this might be helpful to other people too.

Comment: Thanks. "make sure you leave no spaces between the semicolon and the new path."  is such a minute detail, but an important one, and can easily be missed if you're pre-pending new paths.

Comment: mine is not that problem but still not getting

Answer (score 3):

Here iam sharing some screenshot about adding **Environment variables** in **windows 10 PC**

### Step 1

Open Control panel and search for environment variable.

[image: Open Control panel and search for environment variable.]

### Step 2

Select Environment variable.

[image: Select]

### Step 3

Select path that shown in the below image.

## [image]

### Step 4

click on edit button.

[image]

### Step 5

Click new button.

[image]

### Step 6

Add your php file path like given below.

> Path may different according to your server.

Then click Ok that's It.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In latest Xampp, path to PHP.exe has changed to this. Means we will have to add this new path in our PATH environment as I mentioned at another Stackoverflow Question.
[PHP.exe new Path in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71008833/2626094)