# PHP command not found in my shell for windows 10 neither in git bash. I tried all the available solution from here

Tags: php, command-line, xampp, windows-10

When I typed php in my command prompt, It results

```
C:\Users\samsung>php
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have installed xampp in my windows 10 and I haven't edited the php.ini file in the settings. Any help to enable this php command would be greatly appreciated because I am stock in my laravel composer setup due to this.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 17):

If you are using windows:

1. Open My Computer Properties
2. Click on Advance System Setting
3. Select Environment Variables
4. Click on Path & Edit
5. Click new & Add your PHP.exe path (e.g. C:\xampp\php\php.exe) 
   [As shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjpeU.png)

then **Restart**

Detail Support available [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)

Answer (score 6):

You should add the php.exe path to PATH environment variable

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Answer (score 6):

Install composer, during the installation process allow composer to add php to your path:

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Install composer, during the installation process allow composer to add php to your path:

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Comment: No, I mean, you can delete your answer, and put it as a comment in the original question or in one of the answers, where you see it fit best