# PHP is not recognized as an internal or external command, the program can be operated or batch files

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I got the following error when I run a command with php:

```
D:\laragon\www\Cultivation>php artisan migrate
```

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Why I get this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP command not found in my shell for windows 10 neither in git bash. I tried all the available solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962406/php-command-not-found-in-my-shell-for-windows-10-neither-in-git-bash-i-tried-al)

Comment: installed in drive :D

Comment: D:\file-software\PhpStorm 2020.2

Comment: thank you so much! i did it!!

Answer (score 1):

1. open Advanced system setting
2. click on environment variable
3. in system variable section find Path and edit this
4. add php path (for example "C:/xampp/php") and save it

or if you use phpstorm terminal do this

1. open phpstorm setting in file menu
2. go to tools tab
3. click on terminal
4. add php path in environment variable