# Laravel Installation in Windows without XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php

Hi I have installed **PHP 7.1.1** in my Windows OS and also installed **Composer** as a dependency manager of PHP.
Then i installed Laravel using the command:

> composer global require "laravel/installer"

But after that when i try to create a project using the command

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test_blogs

I get the following error:

**Installing laravel/laravel (v5.3.16)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.3.16) Loading from cache
Created project in test_blogs

> php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
>   'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Script php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" handling the post-root-package-install event returned with error code 1**

Here one thing to mention that i am not using XAMPP or WAMPP. And current MySQL is also not installed in my system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php is not recognized as an internal or external command in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Just a question why would you install Laravel with out xampp or mysql

Comment: Cause i don't need to work with Database now.  I i will run it to server later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add php executable path to your PATH variable of your OS, i.e. in windows generaly

> Go to MyComputer->properties->Advanced system setting >Environment Variables> Select PATH and Click Edit

and insert the path of the php end of the line and Save it.

Restart your CMD and type `php -v` it should give you the PHP version

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @msonowal. It worked!!

Comment: i have already upvoted but as my reputation is less than 15, you cannot see the reflection directly but i think it has some reflection overall in the long run and thanks again for your response.

Comment: Done :) @msonowal

Answer (score 0):

You can run laravel installing php on your local machine (windows) but some depeding package inside laravel will not work properly we have to manually config php.ini file inside executable path  insted of doing that you can use laravel homestead

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/homestead