# I have php installed yet I get 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php

I've MAMP installed and am currently watching some Laravel tutorials, however, when I got to the part of making controllers with artisan, I get this error when I type php artisan make:controller.

Comment: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: try add php to environmental variable

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac? That looks like a Windows error in which you need to add an environmental variable to the PHP install https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt