# Magento reindexing CLI command after set variable PATH : 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file

Tags: php, magento2.2

I'm new in Magento. I install magento2 just few days ago and now i want to do reindexing.

But there is no option of reindex in Index Management page. So i used CLI with below code:

```
php bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

Output: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or

batch file.

All of the answer of this question suggest to set environment path variable but the variable path is already set

Link of screenshot :
http://prntscr.com/mc0j95

Please help me to solve this problem.. 
Thanks

Comment: Check this reference URLhop it's useful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt

Comment: I already done this. Still not working

Comment: Come on chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188325/learn-php

Comment: try this :- https://superuser.com/questions/565017/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-windows-7

Comment: yes you can....

Answer (score 1):

Try `php -v` if u dont get the current version maybe u need to reinstall and set the path of PHP again.

Comment: I tried this code in my magento folder, as well as php folder but both shows same error @Juan Carlos Condori

Comment: Try it everywhere, it's just a command to recognize if php is correctly installed.