# How to solve Script php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');" handling the post-root-package-install event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, git, laravel-5

I tried to create a project using this command in git bash

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel cms 5.2.29`

then I got an error that is

Error:

**
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./cms"
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.29)

- Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.29): Loading from cache
  Created project in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms

> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"

'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Script php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');" handling the post-root-package-install event returned with error code 1

**

Then I checked environment variable and there is the path of php and git

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

`C:\Program Files\Git`

After that I added the bash.bashrc file using this command

`alias php='c/xampp/php/php.exe'`

It's not working... I tried to see the version of php in git bash, it's work.
Then I again tried to create project using the same command that I declare before. And again I got this same error.

**Note: this command absolutely work on command prompt**

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt can help?

Comment: No it's not working @MehrdadDastgir